# Verify digital signature in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

How do I verify a sender's email digital signature if I use MS Outlook (2010/2013/2016) as my mail client?

Answer (score 2):

By digital signatures I assume you are referring to emails signed using S/MIME (Secure/Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions).

From the Microsoft Office support site, this [link](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/How-to-tell-if-a-digital-signature-is-trustworthy-0464F8AB-FEFA-4BC7-AF0D-E07A12F7097E#bm3)[1] should answer your question.

> 1. Open the digitally signed message.
> 2. Look at the Signed By status line and note the e-mail address of the
>      person who signed the message.
> 3. Check to see whether the signature is valid or invalid.
>
>    - If the button on the Signed By status line appears similar to the following Signature button Button image , the signature is valid. For
>        more information about the status of the signature, click the button.
>    - If a red underline appears under the Signed By status line and if the button appears as an exclamation mark, the signature is invalid.
>        For more information about the status of the signature, click the
>        button.

[1] https://support.office.com/en-US/article/How-to-tell-if-a-digital-signature-is-trustworthy-0464F8AB-FEFA-4BC7-AF0D-E07A12F7097E#bm3